# After upgrade to 4.2.1 how to get "settings" and "screen lock" back in pull down menu?

Tags: settings, nexus-7, 4.2-jelly-bean, notification-bar

After upgrading my Nexus 7 to 4.2.1, which was an adventure in itself, I noticed that in the pull down menu at the top of the screen (notification bar), where you get to see notifications about updated programs or even available updates, I don't see the icon for "settings" and for the screen lock (so it doesn't readjust when I tilt the screen) anymore. Up to now I was able to use this as a convenient and quick shortcut to go into the settings. Do I now have to pin it to my dock or the home screen in order to have a quick way to access the settings?

How can I get this back in Android 4.2.1, or was this functionality completely stripped from the new release?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swiping down on the left side of the screen should bring down the notification window shade and swiping down on the right side of the screen should bring down the new "quick settings" window shade which has the settings icon and some other handy settings easily available. As far as the screen adjusting, this is known as auto-rotate and can be changed in the quick settings as well (Shown below).

Notification Shade:

[image: Notification Shade]

Quick Settings Shade:

[image]

Comment: Oh, so it does. Thanks for the advice. This will take some getting used to, but it's exactly what I wanted.